# Android handler: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have a thread:

```
public class KelvinThread implements Runnable {

private Handler mSoundHandler;

public KelvinThread() {
    super();
    mSoundHandler = new Handler();
}

private Runnable mSoundThread = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // my treatment
    }
};

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // ....
        mSoundHandler.postDelayed(mSoundThread, 2000);
        // ....
    }
}
```

This thread "KelvinThread" is created and started from another Thread.

I have this error:

> Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

when my handler is allocated : mSoundHandler = new Handler();

Thank you for your help guys !

Comment: In seven hells why you are mixing Handler with native Thread? I think this is very ungly solution and you shouldn't do it - it seems like bad application logic design.

Comment: It is not really. Sometimes you have to do it, for example to trigger UI changes from thread or may other cases. Really depends.

Comment: Hi Ragnar, I read your advice. But how can I do a trigger without Handler ? Is there another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [Looper documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). There is also example.

**UPD**
You might also be able to use Looper.getMainLooper() to attach handler to main looper instead of creating thread one.

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for your advice. I'm novice, so if you have an example according my case, it will be great.

Comment: You can create handler using main looper if that matches your requirements. For example `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

Comment: Vladimir, is it better, in my case, to use Handler notion or to replace it by Timer and TimerTask notion ? I have no UI in my app, it's just a service on a pcDuino board. Thank you very much,

Comment: Timer is java approach which is not recommended in Android, simply because it is based on creating completely new Thread in system with limited resources. For short periods use Handler, for longer AlarmManager. If you loop in your own thread, you can use System.currentTimeMillis() and difference to figure out time out and do your action (timer).